# What kind of type and membership guarantee does a typescript interface provide?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

In this code snippet I am adding a new property to an object type constraint by an interface :

```js
let a: { p1: string, p2: number };
interface i1 { p1: string, p2: number };
let b: i1;

b = { p1: "hello", p2: 3 }; //no error no problem

/*
the following line gives this error: 

Type '{ p1: string; p2: number; p3: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ p1: string; p2: number; }'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'p3' does not exist in type '{ p1: string; p2: number; }'.
*/
a = {p1:"hello",p2:6, p3:3}

//this line give no compile error
a["123"] = 123;
```

I think the type I give **a** using the object literal is equivalent to the type I give to **b** using an interface with the same object literal.

Why am I allowed to add a new property to the object type that does not have that property but I get an error when assigning an object with extra property? Isn't allowing me to add an additional property to a variable of a type that deos not have this property ruining the type guarantee?

[code link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20a%3A%20%7B%20p1%3A%20string%2C%20p2%3A%20number%20%7D%3B%0D%0Ainterface%20i1%20%7B%20p1%3A%20string%2C%20p2%3A%20number%20%7D%3B%0D%0Alet%20b%3A%20i1%3B%0D%0Ab%20%3D%20%7B%20p1%3A%20%22hello%22%2C%20p2%3A%203%20%7D%3B%0D%0Aa%20%3D%20%7Bp1%3A%22hello%22%2Cp2%3A6%2C%20p3%3A3%7D%0D%0Aa%5B%22123%22%5D%20%3D%20123%3B)

Answer (score 3):

The behavior is consistent between an interface and an object type:

```
let a: { p1: string, p2: number };
interface i1 { p1: string, p2: number };
let b: i1;

// both these give an error that p3 are excess properties
b = { p1: "hello", p2: 3, p3: "" }; 
a = {p1:"hello",p2:6, p3:3}
```

The code above gives errors on both `a` and `b` that `p3` should not be there. This feature is called excess property checks and only kicks in on assigning an object literal directly to a variable of a given type. (See [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html))

You are not getting an error on `a["123"] = 123` or `b["123"] = 1123` if you don't have the compiler option `noImplictAny` turned on, this will be the default behavior, you are allowed to index with anything by default.

My recommendation is to turn on `noImplictAny` to forbit indexing into such objects, this is a common source of errors.

If you want to allow indexing into an object you need to be explicit about it by adding an index signature. If you do you can index under `noImplictAny` and the excess property checks error goes away:

```
let a: { p1: string, p2: number; [n: string] : string | number };
interface i1 { p1: string, p2: number; [n: string] : string | number };
let b: i1;

// ok now
b = { p1: "hello", p2: 3, p3: "" }; 
a = {p1:"hello",p2:6, p3:3}

//ok now even under noImplcitAny
a["123"] = 123;
b["123"] = 1123
```